Derive Multiple Keys from password
I am currently building a platform for storing documents for my private use. The goal is to upload only encrypted files.
Therefore i want to use the user password for authentication and also for encryption to decrease complexity for my wife. My current idea is that i generate a hash, that is used as password for auth so that the server does not know the password which then can be used for encryption.
Is this a valid method? The only problem which comes to my mind is that i have to use a different hash algorithm than the encryption algorythm uses for stretching the key.

Passwords should always be stored in hashed form on the server. And if you own the server and it's only for personal use, why are you worried about using the same password for authentication and encryption?

Yeah i know, but if i transmit the password for authentication, the server would be responsible for hashing the password and thus could decrypt the files so my idea was to hash the password twice and send the first created hash as password while the second hash is stored in the db for auth. T
he problem is that i want to build a solution where i dont have to trust the vserver provider. (I could potentially make the account and password static and overcome this issue, but i want to be able to register a user)

Passwords need to be protected with a slow KDF (such as Bcrypt, Scrypt, Argon2, etc) in order to be resilient to cracking. Each key you derive from the password should be derived with a unique salt so that the resulting hashes look unrelated. All keys do not need to be derived with a different call slow KDF, they can use the same one. E.g. in the construction:
key_material = slow_kdf(password, salt=unique_salt)
key_1 = quick_kdf(key_material, salt="key 1")
key_2 = quick_kdf(key_material, salt="key 2")

This should be the most secure way to derive multiple keys from a password.

thanks for the reply. Does the unique salt need any type of protection or can it be made available over a public api?

No it doesn't need to be secret. Having it be public opens the door to precomputation attacks where an attacker can start computing possible hashes before the database has been breached, and then they check if any of them match once the database is breached. This is only a theoretical attack since the table would need to be built from scratch for each user. And thus it would only ever be the slightest concern against super high profile targets, and even then it isn't considered practical. So that attack vector should be of no concern.

The web crypto api does not provide scrypt or bcrypt and using a javascript package would be relativly slow. Is it possible to use PBKDF2 with a high number of iterations(64000) as the slow_kdf?

It is of course possible to use PBKDF2 but not optimal since attacks against it are much more efficient than towards the other algorithms mentioned. But if you can't use anything else then make sure all users have good passwords and use a high number of iterations. 64k iterations is not high enough, so see for example OWASPs page for their current recommendations: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html#pbkdf2

thanks, for the advice. I will keep the owasp cheat sheets in mind. I also found a library for the recommended argon2id hash (https://www.npmjs.com/package/hash-wasm)
The Configuration now is:
argon2Id({iterations:5, parallelism: 1, memorysize: 47104, hashLength: 32, salt: unique_salt})
If i use this parameters for all 3 keys it calculates the keys in 800ms in the web browser of the client.

Here is my current implementation in case someone wants to check it or has the same needs:
import { argon2id } from 'hash-wasm';

export interface PasswordKeys {
  passwordKey: string;
  encryptionKey: CryptoKey;
}

async function generateKeys(password: string, salt: Uint8Array): Promise<PasswordKeys> {
  const masterKey = await argon2id({
      password: password,
      salt: salt, 
      parallelism: 1,
      iterations: 5,
      memorySize: 47104, 
      hashLength: 32,
      outputType: 'binary'
    });

    const passwordKey = await argon2id({
      password: masterKey,
      salt: 'some salt for the password Key'
      parallelism: 1,
      iterations: 5,
      memorySize: 47104, 
      hashLength: 32,
      outputType: 'hex', 
    });

    const encryptionKeyData = await argon2id({
      password: masterKey,
      salt: 'some salt for the encryption key',
      parallelism: 1,
      iterations: 5,
      memorySize: 47104
      hashLength: 32,
      outputType: 'binary',
    });

    const encryptionKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
      'raw',
      encryptionKeyData,
      { name: 'AES-GCM', length: 256 },
      false,
      ['encrypt', 'decrypt']
    );

  return { passwordKey, encryptionKey };
}


It is not efficient use of resources to use Argon2 for the passwordKey and encryptionKey, you only need to do that for the masterKey and then use a much lighter KDF (such as HKDF) for the other two. This way you can make your Argon2 instance for the masterKey three times slower without increasing overall time spent hashing, and increases the strength of the key strenghtening by ~50%.
